# HOOK C# method in DLL

Tags: c#, hook

I have C# application which calls `SUM()` function from a DLL.

I want to hook that `SUM()` function in the DLL and manipulate the instructions by injecting my DLL into the process of C# application.

Please reply.

Comment: Read and try - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal This has nothing to do with window hooking

Comment: Is the Sum function virtual or exposed through an interface?

Comment: There's no mechanism for this in managed code, you cannot hook the just-in-time compiler.  Thankfully.  A common approach is to rewrite the IL in the assembly.  Before you run the code.  Review PostSharp.

Comment: To clarify: do you want to hook the "native" SUM() function in Excel from a C# application?

Answer (score 2):

Please see this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463508/Net-CLR-Injection-Modify-IL-Codes-on-Run-time

You can do that by modifying the IL code on runtime