# loading Net. DLL files into my project dynamicly

Tags: c#, dll

I don't want this : `Assembly.LoadFrom(PathToAssembly)`.

I need to really bring the dll in the run time code to my project and then use it's classes normally without the activator class. Exactly like I load a net. dll file into my project not in run time but now I need to add during the run time.

Comment: Add a reference to it in your solution.

Comment: What's wrong with Assembly.LoadFrom? It loads dynamically

Comment: does dll hooking answer to your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101223/hook-c-sharp-method-in-dll

Comment: This sounds like you need help with implementing a solution, what's the actual problem? Maybe we could help more with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this scenario you would follow the interface pattern.  Where you create an interface class with all of the desired method stubs.  You would still perform you Assembly.Load, but you then cast the resulting activated object to your interface class.

I don't have an example in c#, but this vb.net should be easy to follow.

```
Dim alib As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Application.StartupPath & "\\PeriodicMinimumsUtilities.dll")
Dim adeb As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Application.StartupPath & "\\PeriodicMinimumsUtilities.pdb")
Dim assembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(alib, adeb)
Dim type As Type = Assembly.GetType("PeriodicMinimumsUtilities.frmPeriodicMinimumsReconcilliation")
Dim obj As Fireblade.POS.Business.IPeriodicMinimumsUtilities = Activator.CreateInstance(type)
```

Interface:

```
Public Interface IPeriodicMinimumsUtilities

    WriteOnly Property Database() As Meritsoft.GolfRez.Data.Database
    Function LoadMinimumsDataSource(ByVal v_fiscalYear As String, ByVal v_fiscalPeriod As Integer) As DataSet
    Function GetMinimumsSpent(ByVal v_fiscalYear As String, ByVal v_fiscalPeriod As Integer) As DataTable
    Function LoadFiscalPeriodsDataSource(ByVal ImposeLimit As Boolean) As DataSet

End Interface
```

Comment: Also known as **Dependency Injection** : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection

Comment: This is not Dependency Injection, This is not passing in Objects a class depends on through its constructor or properties. This is just using interfaces where the implementation happens to be in a dynamically loaded dll.

Comment: Populating a variable with an implementation of an interface that is "not known at compile time" (or in other words, that is not a dependency of the assembly) do follow the Dependency Injection pattern, as **Martin Fowler** say here : http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#FormsOfDependencyInjection

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to reference DLL like you usually do to be able to just "use" it
2. Then, use `LoadFrom` or, for example, you can embed assembly as resource, and load it from stream

Comment: Referencing a DLL in a project does not qualify as loading it in run time.

Comment: Aaaand? That's why you need item 2.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way to dynamically load an assembly in .Net at run time than the methods offered by `Assembly`. Perhaps you have a more specific problem related to the method call you mention. If so, specify it by updating your question so that the community can assist you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the type information (using classes normally) and load the dll at run time, since you would have no type information to compile with.

You can use interfaces normally and load the dll against interfaces, or you can just reference the dll and use the classes normally.

A third option (but a terrible idea) would be to reflect all the classes you are trying to use, using helper methods and strings to identify properties and methods. Not a normal way of using classes but it would actualy compile without the type information being present.