# How to overwrite a function of a 3rd party C# App?

Tags: c#, hook

Given a C# Applications which doesn't recive any updates from the developers anymore.
It has a crucial bug in a certain function.
Is there any way to run the programm with a modified function which fixes that issue?

Or even better just replacing a command inside the function? Due to the fact the target function is very long and a local change would be enough.
The target command contains multiple lines inside of braces.

Comment: fork it from GitHub. Unless you don´t have the sourcecode there´s no way to alter an existing program. Would be a real big security-issue if you could do that, wouldn´t it? Just imagine you´d replace a function of your OS just because you feel there´s a bug inside.

Comment: It really depends on the code. Maybe it is `virtual`, or an interface implementation, etc. maybe you can give more information about the details?

Comment: @HimBromBeere its closes source code. Decompling it will result in a lot of errors. But I know the name of the function I would like to change. And I'm pretty sure it does work somehow with using some low level code. But I would like to avoid installing additional risky software.

Comment: @mu88 it's inside a public static function of a public class

Comment: Than there is no chance but copying and fixing the code, I assume

Comment: Sounds similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11101223/1997232).